# Alter the location and the background color of EditPar

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

I have an EditPart I need to alter its location and background color.
I have managed to alter its location using:

```
ChangeBoundsRequest request = new ChangeBoundsRequest(RequestConstants.REQ_MOVE);
    request.setEditParts(editPart);
    request.setMoveDelta(newLocation);

    Command cmd = editPart.getCommand(request);
    if (cmd != null && cmd.canExecute()) {
        cmd.execute();
    }
```

I have managed to alter the background color by:

```
editPart.getContentPane().setBackgroundColor(color);
```

But whenever I close and re open the application,the color changes I made goes away!

How can I commit the background color !

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1- Enable the "Fill Color" of the element:
http://gmfsamples.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gmf_tutorial9

2- Alter the background Color via:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/GMF_Newsgroup_Q_and_A#How_do_I_change_the_color_of_a_line_using_an_action.3F

instead of using "ID_LINECOLOR",use "ID_FILLCOLOR" to alter the background color.